# Macbook 15" showing green distorted logo and wont start

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have macbook pro 15" (late 2011). Its showing a distorted green logo and loading bar on starting. Its taking around 10 min then showing just white screen. I tried resetting pram, but its still the same. What might be the issue ? How to fix ?

[image]

Comment: ehhh, did you purchase it recently? or is this your computer you've had for a while? and when did this start?

Comment: I am using this from 2012  it was working just fine a couple of hours ago. I put it in sleep mode and tried to wake it after an hour or so ... It didn't wake so I put the power button for 10 seconds... And this hell happened !!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152586)

Comment: I'd start by checking if you're eligible under the [Apple Repair Extension Program](https://www.apple.com/uk/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) as I think that model may qualify.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have a dying/dead discreet GPU, as that's a known problem with your model of MacBook Pro. Booting into safe mode may be doing something to help your GPU (I have an Xserve with a confirmed dying GPU that boots in safe mode but not without it) so it boots properly. I would *highly* recommend getting your MacBook Pro replaced as soon as possible via [the Apple program](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/). I would suggest you run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and verify that your GPU is dead/dying, but this may not be possible given your current state. Similarly, you can run a GPU stress test program like [Unigine Heaven](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/heaven/) and see if your GPU quits.

In any case, seeing if you can get your computer replaced probably isn't a bad idea since it's pretty likely your GPU is dying. Go to an Apple store, explain the issue, and they'll probably give you a new computer.